# Input range slider with specific number

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I contain a slider which uses an input range the current numbers are

> 12, 24, 36, 48, 60

I need to add the ability to contain

> 24, 36, 48, 60, 120

```
<input type="range" data-id='slider1RangePicker' name="range"
       class="form-range slider range" min="24" max="120" step="12"
       id="slider1">

<ul class="range-labels">
 <li class="active selected">24</li>
 <li>36</li>
 <li>48</li>
 <li>60</li>
 <li>120</li>
</ul>
```

previously I would set the min as 12 max as 60 and then a step of 12 which allows it to range correctly.

However with adding 120 and removing 24 and setting the min max accordingly the step number no longer works because of the 60-120 jump.

How would I solve this?

Comment: You have an irregular step now...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes what would be the way to integrate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a contiguous range from 0..max. You no longer have a linear axis, it it essentially a category axis now.

You can use JavaScript to synchronize the labels to the slider like so:

**Note:** To get the current value, you can use `getSlider($rangeSlider).dataset.value`.

```js
const $rangeSlider = document.querySelector('.range-slider');

// Handle slider change
$rangeSlider.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  syncRangeSlider(e.currentTarget);
});

// Handle label click
$rangeSlider.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    getSlider(e.currentTarget).value = getElementIndex(e.target);
  }
  syncRangeSlider(e.currentTarget);
});

// Initial sync
syncRangeSlider($rangeSlider);

function syncRangeSlider(rangeSliderEl) {
  const slider = getSlider(rangeSliderEl);
  const index = slider.valueAsNumber;
  let labelValue;
  getLabels(rangeSliderEl).forEach((label, currIndex) => {
    const isActive = currIndex === index;
    if (isActive) {
      labelValue = +label.textContent;
    }
    toggleLabelActive(label, isActive);
  });
  slider.dataset.value = labelValue;
}

function toggleLabelActive(label, active) {
  label.classList.toggle('active', active);
  label.classList.toggle('selected', active);
}

function getSlider(rangeSliderEl) {
  return rangeSliderEl.querySelector('.slider.range');
}

function getLabels(rangeSliderEl) {
  return rangeSliderEl.querySelectorAll('.range-labels li');
}

function getElementIndex(element) {
  return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(element.parentNode.children, element);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.range-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: thin solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #EEE;
}

.range-slider .slider.range {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

.range-slider .range-labels {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.range-slider .range-labels li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: thin solid #CCC;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 2rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.range-slider .range-labels li.active.selected {
  background: #FFA;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider">
  <input
    type="range"
    id="slider1"
    name="range"
    class="form-range slider range"
    data-id="slider1RangePicker"
    min="0"
    max="4"
    value="1"
    data-value="24" />
  <ul class="range-labels">
   <li class="active selected">24</li>
   <li>36</li>
   <li>48</li>
   <li>60</li>
   <li>120</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, when it comes to outputting the values currently its 0-4 if i need to grab the exact numbers from the list that is picked will i just need to set 0 = 24. 1 = 26 etc ?

Comment: @Lowtiercoder when the input changes, I set the `dataset` property of `value`. If you request the value of the input, call `input.dataset.value` instead of `input.value`. This will get the real value.

Comment: Polywhirl I followed your solution and it helped me solve my problem. I did a 0-4 min/max with a step of 1 with my specific labels because I needed the value of the step to match 60, 120 etc I ended up just mapping the values to handle this part afterwards. I appreciate the help in pointing me in the right direction .

Answer (score 0):

The [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#list) attribute and `datalist` element can be used to specify the values.

You will also need a small script to block the intermediate positions.

```js
const sliderInput = document.querySelector('#slider1');
const sliderValOpts = document.querySelectorAll('#slider1Values option');

const valOut = document.querySelector("#valueOutput");
valOut.textContent = sliderInput.value;

sliderInput.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  const evtVal = parseInt(evt.target.value);
  for (const opt of sliderValOpts) {
    const val = parseInt(opt.value);
    if (val >= evtVal) {
      evt.target.value = val;
      break;
    }
  }
  valOut.textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="range" data-id="slider1RangePicker" name="range" class="form-range slider range" min="24" max="120" step="1" id="slider1" list="slider1Values" value="60">

<datalist id="slider1Values">
  <option value="24"></option>
  <option value="36"></option>
  <option value="48"></option>
  <option value="60"></option>
  <option value="120"></option>
</datalist>

<p>Value: <output id="valueOutput"></output></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I did not know about the [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element!